# Cruzar datos de dos tablas diferentes

Tags: sql, ms-access

Soy totalmente nuevo en este mundo y tengo una tarea a realizar la cual no se hacer. Imaginaros que en vuestra empresa teneis el registro de todas las llamadas de atención al cliente, esas llamadas se clasifican en una serie de  categorias y atributos diferentes, un ejemplo de categoría seria “proceso de alta” es decir esa llamada pertenece al proceso de alta y por el otro lado, un ejemplo de atributo, sería “buen trato”, es decir esa llamada se clasifica como que ha recidibido un buen trato. El caso es el siguiente: yo tengo todas las llamadas clasificadas como proceso de alta y todas las llamadas a las que se les atribuye un buen trato en **dos tablas diferentes** ¿como podría hacer para identificar el número total de llamadas que pertenecen a un buen trato y proceso de alta a la vez?

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Saludos @PabloDiazDeMera, lastimosamente en este sitio no realizamos tareas ni hacemos cualquier otro trabajo que solo tenga el encabezado del problema, primeramente debes intentar resolverlo investigando lo que puedas y cuando ya vayas avanzando y te estanques en el proceso pregunta en este sitio sobre ese punto donde te estancaste y así tendrás un problema específico que la comunidad recibirá de mejor manera. ;)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cruce datos MS Access](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/583242/cruce-datos-ms-access)