# Cruce datos MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

soy totalmente nuevo en este mundo y me gustaría que alguien pudiese ayudarme. Yo tengo una tabla en MS Access la cual contiene todas las llamadas de atención al cliente de una empresa clasificadas en una serie de atributos y categorías, un ejemplo de categoría sería "proceso de alta" es decir, la llamada pertenece al proceso de alta ya que el cliente de esa llamada quiere darse de alta en el servicio. Por el otro lado, tenemos los atributos, por ejemplo, "buen trato" es decir, el cliente ha recibido un buen trato por parte del agente en esa llamada.

Yo lo que he hecho, ha sido coger todas las llamadas con sus atributos y categorías de la tabla inicial y dividirla en dos, adjunto imagen de la tabla de atributos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, en las columnas aparecen los respectivos atributos y en las filas el número de la llamada, es decir, la llamada nº18 pertenece a trato correcto. La tabla de categorías es exactamente igual que la que os acabo de enseñar pero en vez de tener atributos en sus columnas, tiene categorías. Ahora la cuestión es, ¿cómo podría cruzar atributos con categorías? es decir, necesito el número de llamadas que pertenezcan a "proceso de alta" y "trato correcto" a la vez, y así con todas las categorías y atributos: "proceso de alta" con "redirección", "proceso de alta" con "insatisfacción"... hasta terminar, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Pablo, lo primero de todo para que té funcione lo que pides, las tablas deben de estar relacionadas entre si. ¿ Lo están ?. Una vez estén relacionadas solo se debe de realizar una consulta. Un ejemplo seria el siguiente: 
Abra la base de datos y, en la pestaña Crear, haga clic en Diseño de consulta.
En la pestaña Tablas, haga doble clic en la tabla Productos.
Supongamos que en la tabla Productos tenemos los campos Nombre de producto y Precio listado. Haga doble clic en Nombre de producto y Precio listado para agregar estos campos a la cuadrícula de diseño de la consulta.
Diseño y ejec

Comment: Hola Joan, agradezco tu respuesta pero lo que me estas diciendo que haga es que simplemente muestre campos de una tabla en una consulta ¿no?  yo necesito encontrar coincidencias etre dos campos distintos de dos tablas distintas que no tienen ninguna relación entre sí

Comment: Ejemplos???? todo se puede, el tema es que puede que salgan datos totalmente ilogicos... con hacer un join, vos podes unir las tablas que quieras por los campos que quieras... de ahi a que sea logico, es otro problema...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Tu diseño actual de datos imposibilita lo que quieres (o no al menos de una forma sencilla y fácil). Necesitas 3 tablas:

1. Una lista de las categorías posibles
2. Una lista de los atributos posibles
3. Una tercera tabla donde se relacione 1 llamada con 1 categoría y 1 atributo

Damos por hecho que cada llamada puede tener solamente 1 atributo y 1 categoría: en caso contrario necesitas un planteamiento algo más complejo que tendrás que desarrollar.

Como ejemplo, un pantallazo de 3 tablas falsas que he creado en una base de datos en access (porque tu imagen se ve muy mal así que me lo he inventado):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta estructura se pueden crear consultas de totales (GROUP BY en SQL) que te permitan obtener datos agregados:

> [Consultas con Totales en
> Access](https://teformas.com/office/access/consultas-con-totales-access/)

En mi ejemplo mi código SQL es:

```
SELECT T_REGISTRO.id_categoria, T_REGISTRO.id_atributo, Count(T_REGISTRO.id_llamada) AS CuentaDeid_llamada
FROM T_REGISTRO
GROUP BY T_REGISTRO.id_categoria, T_REGISTRO.id_atributo;
```

Y obtenemos justo lo que pides: el recuento de llamadas desglosado por categorías y atributos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, esta estructura permite, de una manera cómoda, [usando el asistente de no coincidentes](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/comparar-dos-tablas-y-buscar-registros-no-coincidentes-cb20ad48-4eba-402a-b20d-eaf10a5d1cb4), ver si, por ejemplo, hay algún atributo que tenga 0 llamadas. En mi caso el SQL es así:

```
SELECT T_ATRIBUTOS.ATRIBUTO, Count(T_REGISTRO.id_atributo) AS CuentaDeid_atributo
FROM T_ATRIBUTOS LEFT JOIN T_REGISTRO ON T_ATRIBUTOS.[ATRIBUTO] = T_REGISTRO.[id_atributo]
WHERE (((T_REGISTRO.id_atributo) Is Null))
GROUP BY T_ATRIBUTOS.ATRIBUTO;
```

Y el resultado es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto quiere decir que, de todas las llamadas recibidas, **ninguna** tiene ese atributo. Es información interesante saber eso de unos datos.

Te he subido el Access a Gdrive para que veas un poco cómo está estructurado todo, las relaciones, las claves principales, etc. Te puede servir de ejemplo para diseñar algo por tu cuenta.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/18H5e5Q1A_2VeG4ppeHwW3W8KD3RjETbV/view?usp=share_link